# How to create quarterly data in R

Tags: r

I have daily scores and their corresponding dates as seen below and currently struggling to convert them to quarterly. However, the years are first of all not chronological and am quite confused as to how to deal with the two situations.
see sample.
data

```
                         dates score
1          July 1, 2019 Monday     8
2      October 25, 2015 Sunday    -3
3      June 17, 2020 Wednesday    -5
4   January 17, 2018 Wednesday    -1
5        April 15, 2019 Monday     6
6   October 30, 2019 Wednesday    10
7         March 6, 2017 Monday    -2
8     November 19, 2018 Monday     3
9       June 11, 2020 Thursday     5
10  October 11, 2017 Wednesday   -13
11     December 3, 2017 Sunday    -8
12 November 14, 2018 Wednesday    -6
13     August 22, 2017 Tuesday     8
14 December 13, 2017 Wednesday     5
15     January 22, 2016 Friday     5`
```

```
dates <- sapply(date, function(x) 
                trimws(grep(paste(month.name, collapse = '|'), x, value = TRUE))); 
sort(as.Date(dates,'%B %d, %Y %A'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for [lubridate](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/). You can parse your date column with `lubridate::parse_date_time()` and extract the quarter they fall in with `lubridate::quarter()`:

```r
library("tibble")
library("dplyr")
library("lubridate")

tbl <-  tribble(~date,                         ~score,
                "July 1, 2019 Monday",          8,
                "October 25, 2015 Sunday",     -3,
                "June 17, 2020 Wednesday",     -5,
                "January 17, 2018 Wednesday",  -1,
                "April 15, 2019 Monday",        6,
                "October 30, 2019 Wednesday",  10,
                "March 6, 2017 Monday",        -2,
                "November 19, 2018 Monday",     3,
                "June 11, 2020 Thursday",       5,
                "October 11, 2017 Wednesday", -13,
                "December 3, 2017 Sunday",     -8,
                "November 14, 2018 Wednesday", -6,
                "August 22, 2017 Tuesday",      8,
                "December 13, 2017 Wednesday",  5,
                "January 22, 2016 Friday",      5)

tbl %>% 
  mutate(date = parse_date_time(date, "B d, Y")) %>% 
  mutate(quarter = quarter(date, with_year = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 15 x 3
#>    date                score  quarter
#>    <dttm>              <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 2019-07-01 00:00:00     8   2019.3
#>  2 2015-10-25 00:00:00    -3   2015.4
#>  3 2020-06-17 00:00:00    -5   2020.2
#>  4 2018-01-17 00:00:00    -1   2018.1
#>  5 2019-04-15 00:00:00     6   2019.2
#>  6 2019-10-30 00:00:00    10   2019.4
#>  7 2017-03-06 00:00:00    -2   2017.1
#>  8 2018-11-19 00:00:00     3   2018.4
#>  9 2020-06-11 00:00:00     5   2020.2
#> 10 2017-10-11 00:00:00   -13   2017.4
#> 11 2017-12-03 00:00:00    -8   2017.4
#> 12 2018-11-14 00:00:00    -6   2018.4
#> 13 2017-08-22 00:00:00     8   2017.3
#> 14 2017-12-13 00:00:00     5   2017.4
#> 15 2016-01-22 00:00:00     5   2016.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change `dates` column to Date class you can use `as.Date`.

```
df$new_date <- as.Date(trimws(df$dates), '%B %d, %Y')
```

Or this should also work with `lubridate`'s `mdy` :

```
df$new_date <- lubridate::mdy(df$dates)
```

Comment: but the problem now is how to construct quarterly dates out of the dates?                                         [32847]]
[1] "June 6, 2019 Thursday"

[[32848]]
[1] "March 22, 2016 Tuesday"

[[32849]]
[1] "September 2, 2018 Sunday"

[[32850]]
[1] "April 13, 2014 Sunday"

[[32851]]
[1] "June 6, 2017 Tuesday"

[[32852]]
[1] "June 11, 2020 Thursday"

[[32853]]
[1] "June 10, 2020 Wednesday"

[[32854]]
[1] "October 20, 2016 Thursday"

[[32855]]
[1] "June 22, 2019 Saturday"

[[32856]]
[1] "May 26, 2020 Tuesday"

[[32857]]
[1] "March 19, 2016 Saturday"

Answer (score 0):

Once the data has been converted to date values per Ronak Shah's answer, we can use `lubridate::quarter()` to generate year and quarter values.

```
textData <- "                      dates|score
        July 1, 2019 Monday|    8
    October 25, 2015 Sunday|   -3
    June 17, 2020 Wednesday|   -5
 January 17, 2018 Wednesday|   -1
      April 15, 2019 Monday|    6
 October 30, 2019 Wednesday|   10
       March 6, 2017 Monday|   -2
   November 19, 2018 Monday|    3
     June 11, 2020 Thursday|    5
 October 11, 2017 Wednesday|  -13
    December 3, 2017 Sunday|   -8
November 14, 2018 Wednesday|   -6
    August 22, 2017 Tuesday|    8
December 13, 2017 Wednesday|    5
    January 22, 2016 Friday|    5
"
df <- read.csv(text=textData,
               header=TRUE,
               sep="|")
library(lubridate)
df$dt_quarter <- quarter(mdy(df$dates),with_year = TRUE,
                         fiscal_start = 1)
head(df)
```

We include `with_year = TRUE` and `fiscal_start = 1` arguments to illustrate that one can change the output to include / exclude the year information, as well as change the start month for the year from the default of 1.

...and the output:

```
> head(df)
                        dates score dt_quarter
1         July 1, 2019 Monday     8     2019.3
2     October 25, 2015 Sunday    -3     2015.4
3     June 17, 2020 Wednesday    -5     2020.2
4  January 17, 2018 Wednesday    -1     2018.1
5       April 15, 2019 Monday     6     2019.2
6  October 30, 2019 Wednesday    10     2019.4
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ Len Greski  and @Ronak Shah

Answer (score 0):

The `yearqtr` class represents a year and quarter as the year plus 0 for Q1, 0.25 for Q2, 0.5 for Q3 and 0.75 for Q4.  If date is defined as a `yearqtr` object as below then `as.integer(date)` is the year and `cycle(date)` is the quarter: 1, 2, 3 or 4.   Note that junk at the end of the date field is ignored by `as.yearqtr` so we only need to specify month, day and year percent codes.

If you want a `Date` object instead of a `yearqtr` object then uncomment one of the commented out lines.

`data` is defined reproducibly in the Note at the end.  (In the future please use `dput` to display your input data to prevent ambiguity as discussed in the information at the top of the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag page.)

```
library(zoo)

date <- as.yearqtr(data$date, "%B %d, %Y")
# uncomment one of these lines if you want a Date object instead of yearqtr object
# date <- as.Date(date) # first day of quarter
# date <- as.Date(date, frac = 1) # last day of quarter
data.frame(date, score = data$score)[order(date), ]
```

giving the following sorted data frame assuming that we do *not* uncomment any of the commented out lines above.

```
      date score
2  2015 Q4    -3
15 2016 Q1     5
7  2017 Q1    -2
...snip...
```

### Time series

If this is supposed to be a time series with a single aggregated score per quarter then we can get a zoo series like this where `data` is the original data defined in the Note below.

```
library(zoo)

to_ym <- function(x) as.yearqtr(x, "%B %d, %Y")
z <- read.zoo(data, FUN = to_ym, aggregate = "mean")
z
##   2015 Q4   2016 Q1   2017 Q1   2017 Q3   2017 Q4   2018 Q1   2018 Q4   2019 Q2 
## -3.000000  5.000000 -2.000000  8.000000 -5.333333 -1.000000 -1.500000  6.000000 
##   2019 Q3   2019 Q4   2020 Q2 
##  8.000000 10.000000  0.000000
```

or as a `ts` object like this:

```
as.ts(z)
##           Qtr1      Qtr2      Qtr3      Qtr4
## 2015                               -3.000000
## 2016  5.000000        NA        NA        NA
## 2017 -2.000000        NA  8.000000 -5.333333
## 2018 -1.000000        NA        NA -1.500000
## 2019        NA  6.000000  8.000000 10.000000
## 2020        NA  0.000000
```

### Note

The input data in reproducible form:

```
data <- structure(list(dates = c("July 1, 2019 Monday", "October 25, 2015 Sunday", 
"June 17, 2020 Wednesday", "January 17, 2018 Wednesday", "April 15, 2019 Monday", 
"October 30, 2019 Wednesday", "March 6, 2017 Monday", "November 19, 2018 Monday", 
"June 11, 2020 Thursday", "October 11, 2017 Wednesday", "December 3, 2017 Sunday", 
"November 14, 2018 Wednesday", "August 22, 2017 Tuesday", "December 13, 2017 Wednesday", 
"January 22, 2016 Friday"), score = c(8L, -3L, -5L, -1L, 6L, 
10L, -2L, 3L, 5L, -13L, -8L, -6L, 8L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

### Update

Have updated this answer several times so be sure you are looking at the latest version.

Comment: waw, Thank you@ G. Grothendiek

Comment: Dear @G. Grothendieck, I further wish to know in case, the data list of the data frame is long such that, the dates and the scores are very long, say about 40,000 observations, how do I reproduce the INPUT data in the form above?

Comment: If this is to post a problem on SO then create a small example that illustrates it.